# What type of cleaner should I use to remove a puke stain from concrete?

Tags: concrete, basement, cleaning

My cat puked on the basement floor in a couple places, but I can't seem to clean the stain.  So far I've tried simply mopping with Pine-Sol®, which didn't work. Then I tried scrubbing/mopping with OxiClean™, which also didn't work.

Should I try a cleaner that is specifically designed for concrete?

It's a typical poured concrete basement, that doesn't appear to be sealed. Also keep in mind that it is a basement, so it's indoors and doesn't have great ventilation.

[image]
<sup>*Stain after cleaning*</sup>

Comment: Have you seen the type of concrete cleaner for oily stains that you put on, let dry, and then clean up later?  There are several brands [like this one](http://www.pour-n-restore.com/products/oil-stain-remover.html).  I've wanted to try it, but have not yet.

Comment: Doesn't SE provide moderators with personal assistants to handle these kinds of issues?

Comment: @bib diy is an outer rim territory in the SE empire.  We're lucky they even keep the server turned on.

Comment: The server is ***ON***? I thought these were private conversations!?

Answer (score 4):

Muriatic acid in a weak solution with water (10% acid) will clean almost any stain on cement.
Remember to use gloves and if going any stronger than 10% it can make an unpleasant smell.
All swimming pool stores have it and most Home Depot, lows, Jerry’s stores also carry it.
When mixing add the acid to the water (when you open the bottle it will be quite strong so you want to have fresh air).
Put the mix on the area, let sit for a few minutes then mop up and rinse 3 times with water, caution it may make a very clean spot like new cement.

Comment: If your floor is very smooth (finished interior concrete), can the acid leave a rough spot?

Comment: if a strong solution (30%) it will etch and be rough but with a weak solution I dont notice any real diference but the color.

Comment: Hmm... I'm not sure a clean spot is any better than a dirty spot. Ideally I think I'd like to try and keep a fairly even tone.  If I can't find anything better, this might be the way to go though.

Comment: Cat frup = stomach acids - the floor has been acid etched in that spot, so etching it some more to remove the extra-cat-food based colorants that came with the stomach acid is sensible. Otherwise, paint.

Comment: @Tester101 - Do the whole floor and then seal or paint it, but you'd better have the windows open, a fan going and the door closed to the upstairs. - A good summertime project...

Answer (score 0):

Try vinegar & baking soda for a little more bubbly. Just don't pre-mix them in a container. Wet it with the vinegar & cover that with the baking soda & let it sit 10-minutes before wiping off to the side. Then, bring the solution back over if it needs a scrubbing. It should come up, then clean & seal the whole floor to avoid all the effort in the future.